# HTML5 Validate Text input using pattern containing quote

Tags: regex, html

This is not one of these "help me build my regex" questions. I have an HTML form input field where a user can provide geographical position data in various formats. The following regex works fine in [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) as well as in my application. However, I want to use the "pattern" parameter of HTML5 to additionally validate a user's input before submitting it.

```
((([E|W|N|S](\s)?)?([\-]?[0-1]?[(0-9)]{1,2})[°][ ]?([(0-5)]?[(0-9)]{1})([\.|,][0-9]{1,5})?['][ ]?([0-5]{0,1}[0-9]?(([\.|\,])[0-9]{0,3})?)([\"]|[']{2}){0,1}((\s)?[E|W|N|S])?)|([-]?[1]?[0-9]{1,2}[\.|,][0-9]{1,9}))
```

The point is that this regex contains a quote character ("). Now, I put this regex in my input like this:

```
<input type="text" pattern = "regex..."...." />
```

Browsers do not recognize this regex and don't do any validation at all, so obviously I need to escape that quote. What I tried so far:

- PHP's addslashes() function escapes too many characters.
- I escaped the quote with a single backslash

That did not change anything. I tested with Chrome, which works fine with simple regular expressions. The one above obviously is a bit too complicated.

I know the regular expression above is not perfect for matching coordinates, however, this is not to be discussed here. I just would like to know how to correctly escape a pattern in HTML5 as Chrome does not do anything with that regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use HTML entities:

- instead of `'` use `&apos;`
- instead of `"` use `&quot;`

If you're creating the regexp using PHP, you can use `htmlentities()` to encode a string using HTML entities. By default, this will just encode double quotes, but you can use the `ENT_QUOTES` option to encode both types of quotes.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution... even though I regularly use htmlentities() to display data, it did not occur to me that I could use it to encode my regex pattern... Thanks a lot!