# Escaping " and ' in HTML Input Pattern Attribute

Tags: html, input, text, pattern-matching

I need to limit a text input to letters, numbers and a few characters including ' and ". The code I have **without** the ' looks like this: `pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9\s+"*]{3,}'`
This works fine, but when I try to add the ' inside the brackets, escaped or not, it fails. I have looked at all of the answers about patterns and regex here and elsewhere and can't seem to nail it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: PHP  Sorry I left that out.

Comment: Perhaps [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404216/html5-validate-text-input-using-pattern-containing-quote) using `htmlentities`  can be helpfull

Comment: Thank you. `htmlentities` was the answer. I would never have thought to use that solution.

Comment: `pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9\s+\\x22*]{3,}'` or `pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9\s+\x22*]{3,}'` should work, too.